# form_helpers Rails 3 - include objects in the loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes, form-helpers

Tour `has_many :photos`, Photo `belongs_to :tour`.

The fields for a tour are `:title, :description`.

The fields for a photo are `:alt, :image (path), :tour_id`

Tour `accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos`

Tour `attr_accessible :photo_attributes`

--

In the form for Tours, I want to return the respective Tours photos in the form once saved, so the user can see the photos they have uploaded and add their Alt Tags

This is what the form looks like, but I don't know how to bring back any saved images into the form...

```
= semantic_form_for ([:admin, @tour]), :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
...
  - unless @tour.new_record?
    = semantic_fields_for Photo.new do |f|
      = f.file_field :image, :rel => tour_photos_path(@tour)
    - else
      You must save the tour, to be able add photos.

    = f.semantic_fields_for :photos, @tour.photos do |p|

         // If there is a photo, somehow display that image in this form loop...
         = image_tag ## WHAT COULD I PUT HERE? ##

         = f.input :remove_image, :as => :boolean

         = p.inputs
```

I am confused because obviously the form_helper can bring back the saved elements of the form back into the form fields.. but I don't know how I can use one of those saved elements in the image tag...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little hard to understand, but what about something like this?

```
- @tour.photos.each do |photo|
  = image_tag photo.path
  = f.input :remove_image, :as => :boolean
  # etc...
```